# Wrong type for parameter "uri" of resolveLocalFileSystemURI: Expected String, but got Null

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, apache-cordova

I am cureently trying to save a png image from my ionic(v1) application.This works well in android but I have errors in iOS.

The error is

> ERROR: Wrong type for parameter "uri" of resolveLocalFileSystemURI: Expected String, but got Null.

I am using the cordova file plugin .
I am sensing something is wrong with the folder path.

`var folderpath=cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory;`

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is a permission issue? You need to add something to you `config.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `cordova.file.dataDirectory`. 
I stored pdf's using this and it is working fine. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to fix this issue by deleting your platforms folder, or the files inside, and do a 'platform add' afterwards.

Steps to reproduce:

- ionic cordova platform remove ios (or android)
- ionic cordova platform add ios (or android)

Following the steps above fixed the issue for me :).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this question these days... The path is null when there is no user permission. Make sure you acquired correct permissions before trying.